# Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first. The error is not sending message to firebase and application terminated

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have only three line of code to send msg to firebase and when I run app it automatically terminated. I added firebase through Tools menu.

I have tried internet permission to manifest file but didn't work.

```kotlin
var firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
var databaseRef = firebaseDatabase.reference
databaseRef.setValue("Hello There")
```

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
```

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
  }
}
```

> "I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful"
> "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not
> initialized in this process ... Make sure to call
> FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first."

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you need to init the FirebaseApp instance before calling its methods. This it the line:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this); // "this" is a context
```

A common way to do it - to add this line to `onCreate()` method of your custom Application class.

And [here, on Codepath](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class) you can find how to create your custom Application class to put that line in.

**Update**

This will work after you configure the Firebase App project in Firebase Console as well. Don't forget to do the steps [from here, Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: Then start checking everything from the start, as it is impossible in your simple case. Are you sure you did everything from the manual? Did you add the App class name to the Manifest? You can post your Manifest, App and Activity classes here or to pastebin to show what you have. And did you create your Firebase project to the Firebase console, to start with? https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: I create navigation drawer activity project. And yes app class name added to Manifest, and yes I created firebase project.

Comment: Have you checked the Firebase configuration file you've added to the project? 90% probability that you've just missed a step in some configuration. Unfortunately, I'm giving up with the current inputs about the problem.

Comment: Btw, you can add the same line to your Activity, before line var firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(). If it doesn't work this way, that's rather a problem with Firebase config.